# How do I hide a silverlight datagrid row after the row_loading event?

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, datagrid, visibility

Simple one here.
I have created a datagrid, which has a set of rows. I would like to hide specific rows
based on particular logic after the rows have been loaded?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

On a Row Loaded Event i.e LoadingRow, so on each row load you get DataGridRow, where you have datacontext. lets say Person (id, name)

this is how you can play on..

```
 private void dataGrid1_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row != null)
        {
            var row = e.Row.DataContext;
            var person = row as Person;
            if (person != null && person.Id == 2)
            {
                (e.Row as DataGridRow).IsEnabled = false;
            }
            if (person != null && person.Id == 1)
            {
                (e.Row as DataGridRow).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code needs to be tweaked but I was looking for a solution to this and thought it was worth posting it.

```
Private Sub gridComments_LoadingRow(sender As Object, e As DataGridRowEventArgs) Handles gridComments.LoadingRow
        Dim row As DataGridRow = e.Row
        For Each col As DataGridColumn In gridComments.Columns
            Dim g1 As FrameworkElement = col.GetCellContent(e.Row)
            Dim c As UIElement = g1.FindName("ChildElementName")
            c.Opacity = 0 'Change the desired properties here
        Next
    End Sub

private void gridComments_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = e.Row;
    foreach (DataGridColumn col in gridComments.Columns) {
        FrameworkElement g1 = col.GetCellContent(e.Row);
        UIElement c = g1.FindName("ChildElementName");
        c.Opacity = 0;
        //Change the desired properties here
    }
}
```

A bit late but this worked for me.